# Axios response returning empty string

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

```
 axios.post(
                    'http://localhost:3001/users',
                    {
                      username:user.username
                    }
                  ).then((res)=> console.log(res.data))
```

Response From FrontEnd : data: ""

Response i get from postman :

```
[
    {
      
        "Username": "john4",
        "Password": "",
        "Email": "",
        "ProfileImg": "data:image/png;base64,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",
        "Followers": [],
        "Following": [],
        "__v": 0
    }

]
```

im trying to post data and get a response from my server , the server is returning the right data when i use postman but when i use axios i get an empty string any help?

when i console.log(res)

```
{
    "data": "",
    "status": 205,
    "statusText": "Reset Content",
    "headers": {
        "content-length": "2042",
        "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    },
    "config": {
        "transitional": {
            "silentJSONParsing": true,
            "forcedJSONParsing": true,
            "clarifyTimeoutError": false
        },
        "transformRequest": [
            null
        ],
        "transformResponse": [
            null
        ],
        "timeout": 0,
       
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "method": "post",
        "url": "http://localhost:3001/users",
        "data": "{\"username\":\"john4\"}"
    },
    "request": {}
}
```

Comment: Does your setup in Postman mimic the same request you're attempting to make with Axios?

Comment: there both posting the same json object , the server is getting a recieving the request but the response the frontend gets is the problem

Comment: What about headers? Does it match exactly as in postman?

Comment: What happens if you console.log(res)? Do you get anything back from that? Try adding an error catch as well after your .then statement.    .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });

Comment: i added the response to my code the catch does nothing because there is no error.

Comment: are you running this in an async await logic? Firstly, your function should be async await in this case, if it isn't. Then you should make a try catch (so you can also respond with an error). Then your response (which is equal to your post) should be an await.

Answer (score 1):

You should handle your HTTP requests asynchronously with axios, utilizing async await. It just makes it so much cleaner.

Example:

```
const sendGetRequest = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/users', { username: user.username });
        console.log(response.data);
    } catch (err) {
        // Handle Error Here
        console.error(err);
    }
};
```

Calling the function `sendGetRequest()` in this case will send the post request, get the response and console log the response. And since it is utilizing `try catch`, if something goes wrong, it will console log the error.

Also make sure that your axios is properly setup. The correct headers etc. to match whatever you have with postman.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was on my backend i sent res.status(205).json(user) instead of res.status(208).json(user) which somehow bugged it and caused it to send no data.